# Triangle Area Side Side Side

Tags: code-golf, math

Given three sides of a triangle, print area of this triangle.

Test cases:

**In:** `2,3,4`

**Out:** `2.90473750965556`

**In:** `3,4,5`

**Out:** `6`

Given the sides \$a\$, \$b\$, and \$c\$, you can assume that \$a>0\$, \$b>0\$, \$c>0\$, \$a+b>c\$, \$b+c>a\$, and \$c+a>b\$.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer per language in bytes wins.

Comment: What is the required precision? Can the input and outputs be integers? Rounded to the nearest hundredth? Single precision floats? Rationals?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### J, <s>23</s> 19 chars

```
   (4%~2%:[:*/+/-0,+:)

   (4%~2%:[:*/+/-0,+:) 2 3 4
2.90474

   (4%~2%:[:*/+/-0,+:) 3,4,5
6
```

17-char version if input is in `i`: `4%~%:*/(+/,+/-+:)i`

original 23-char version: `(%:@(+/**/@(+/-+:))%4:)`

Answer (score 7):

### APL <s>21</s> 20

Takes screen input via ←⎕

```
(×/(+/t÷2)-0,t←⎕)*.5
```

Answer (score 7):

**Mathematica 23**

```
√Times@@(+##/2-{0,##})&
```

Comment: Just an aside comment. We (usually) try to provide Mma code as functions here. For example in your case `Sqrt[Tr@#*Times@@(Tr@#-2#)]/4&`

Comment: 28 chars, as a function `(Tr@#Times@@(Tr@#-2#))^.5/4&`, or 27 using a variable

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 53

```
t=input()
s=a=sum(t)/2.
for x in t:a*=s-x
print a**.5
```

Input: `2,3,4`

Output: `2.90473750966`

Comment: I wasted a lot of time trying to come up with a better solution. I'm convinced this is as good as it gets

Comment: @jamylak you and me both ;)

Answer (score 5):

### Python 57 bytes

```
a,b,c=input()
s=(a+b+c)*.5
print(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))**.5
```

Using [Heron's Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeronsFormula.html).

Sample usage:

```
$ echo 2,3,4 | python triangle-area.py
2.90473750966

$ echo 3,4,5 | python triangle-area.py
6.0
```

---

**A 58 byte variant:**

```
a,b,c=input()
print((a+b+c)*(b+c-a)*(a+c-b)*(a+b-c))**.5/4
```

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with python, but why is line 2 `*.5` instead of `/2` ?

Comment: @jdstankosky The division operator in Python is by default integer division, so that if the sum of `a+b+c` is odd, the result will be erroneous. This did change in Python 3, although most golf submission are assumed to be Python 2.7 unless otherwise specified (just as Perl submissions are assumed to be 5.10+, and not Perl 6).

Comment: You *could* just say "Python 3" instead of "Python".

Comment: @JoeZ. Nope. This is Python 2; in Python 3, input() returns a string, breaking this solution.

Answer (score 4):

### R : <s>48</s> 43 characters

```
f=function(...)prod(sum(...)/2-c(0,...))^.5
```

Using Heron's formula as well but taking advantage of R's vectorization.
Thanks to @flodel for the idea of the ellipsis.

Usage:

```
f(2,3,4)
[1] 2.904738
f(3,4,5)
[1] 6
```

Comment: you can drop the curly brackets. And you can gain more by using ellipsis: `function(...)prod(sum(...)/2-c(0,...))^.5`. Or even `function(x)prod(sum(x)/2-c(0,x))^.5` if you call your function with a vector.

Comment: @flodel thanks! I didn't thought of the ellipsis, that's nice.

Answer (score 4):

#### GolfScript, 38 characters

```
~].~++:d\{2*d\-*}/'"#{'\+'**0.5/4}"'+~
```

Since the question didn't specify otherwise I chose to work only on integer lengths. Sides must be given on STDIN separated by spaces.

Example:

```
> 2 3 4
2.9047375096555625
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica <s>20</s> 16 or <s>22</s> 18 bytes

With 4 bytes saved by @swish.

This returns an exact answer:

```
Area@SSSTriangle@
```

**Example**

```
Area@SSSTriangle[2,3,4]
```

[image]

---

To return the answer in decimal form, two additional bytes are required.

```
N@Area@SSSTriangle[2,3,4]
```

2.90474

Comment: Composition shaves couple of bytes `Area@*SSSTriangle`

Comment: @swish Thanks, Much appreciated.

Comment: @swish, the multiplication operation, represented by an asterisk, should be dropped.  (I suspect you know that.)

Answer (score 3):

#### APL, <strike>23</strike> 20 characters

```
{(×/(+/⍵÷2)-0,⍵)*÷2} 2 3 4
```

Example:

```
> {(×/(+/⍵÷2)-0,⍵)*÷2} 2 3 4
2.90474
```

Answer (score 3):

## K, 23

```
{sqrt s**/(s:.5*+/x)-x}
```

Example

```
k){sqrt s**/(s:.5*+/x)-x} 2 3 4
2.904738
```

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript, <s>88</s> 85

```
v=prompt().split(/,/g);s=v[0]/2+v[1]/2+v[2]/2;Math.sqrt(s*(s-v[0])*(s-v[1])*(s-v[2]))
```

Not good but fun :) Also Heron...
Demonstrates the ungolfability of simple problems in JS lol

**Note**: run from console to see result.

88->85: Removed `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: You can save a bit by only dividing by 2 once. And you don't actually gain anything by assigning to variables: `(a=v[0])a` is longer than `v[0]v[0]`.

Comment: If I divided by 2 only one time, like `s=(v[0]+v[1]+v[2])/2` with a,b,c=3,4,5 would result in `"345"/2=172.5" and not 6. Improved without `a`, `b` and `c` though.

Comment: Ah, JavaScript's wonderful type system. Ok, `s=(-v[0]-v[1]-v[2])/2` and change the other `-` to `+`. It's an even number of terms, so it cancels out.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 55 bytes

```c
#define f(a,b,c)sqrt((a+b+c)*(a+b-c)*(a-b+c)*(b+c-a))/4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIU0jUSdJJ1mzuLCoREMjUTtJO1lTC0TrgmldCB9I6iZqauqb/M9NzMzT0KzmUigoyswrSdNQUk2LyVPSSdMw0jHWMdHUtMaUAYrrmIJkav//S07LSUwv/q@bkwsA)

Yet another implementation of Hero's formula.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
SH;_P½ʋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/Ywzo@4NDeU93/D7c/alrz/390tJGOsY5JrE40kNQxjY0FAA)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>78</s> 77

```
<?=sqrt(($s=array_sum($c=fgetcsv(STDIN))/2)*($s-$c[0])*($s-$c[1])*$s-=$c[2]);
```

Useage:

```
php triangle.php
2,3,4
```

Output: `2.9047375096556`

I don't think I can make it shorter? I'm still new to golfing. Anyone let me know if I overlooked something.

Thanks Primo for saving me 1 byte, lol.

Comment: The final `($s-$c[2])` can be replaced with `$s-=$c[2]` for one byte, but that's all I can see.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell: 51 (27) characters

```
readLn>>=(\l->print$sqrt$product$map(sum l/2-)$0:l)
```

A very straight-forward implementation of Heron's formula. Example run:

```
Prelude> readLn>>=(\l->print$sqrt$product$map(sum l/2-)$0:l)
[2,3,4]
2.9047375096555625
Prelude>
```

Note that it accepts any numeric input, not only integers. And if the input already is in l the solution only needs to be 36 characters long, and if we are not interested in printing the answer the solution only needs to be 30 characters long. What more is that if we can allow ourself to change the input format we can remove 3 more characters. So if our input looks like [2,3,4,0.0] and is already in l we can get our answer with only:

```
sqrt$product$map(sum l/2-)l
```

Example run:

```
Prelude> let l = [2,3,4,0.0]
Prelude> sqrt$product$map(sum l/2-)l
2.9047375096555625
Prelude>
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (84 <strike>86</strike>)

```
s=(eval('abc '.split('').join('=prompt()|0;'))+a+b)/2;Math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
```

Another JavaScript solution based on Heron's formula, but trying a different approach for loading variables.  Needs to be run from the console.  Each side is entered in a separate prompt.

**EDIT**: Make use of return value of `eval` to save 2 characters.  Beats @tomsmeding, wahoo! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl, 74 chars.

```
proc R {a b c} {set s ($a+$b+$c)/2.
expr sqrt($s*($s-$a)*($s-$b)*($s-$c))}
```

Pass the sides as argument.

For the input `2 3 4` the value of `s` is `(2+3+4)/2.` as string. Double evaluation FTW.

Comment: As a `proc`, it extends to only 81 bytes: 
https://tio.run/##NYo7CoAwEAV7T/GKLYyigp@L2EqKZEknGLMRBPHsMaAWwzAwkdeUfNgYMy4DC75xiYsQlGRqsjWx6vq28EcULO70AbKHWJJUmYaMem0/s1L6Tu89o8eAURd/5sCk0wM

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
4⁻¹√(sum(Ansprod(sum(Ans)-2Ans
```

Starting from a Heron's Formula routine [written by Kenneth Hammond (Weregoose)](http://adriweb.free.fr/upload/ti/weregoose.html), I golfed off two bytes. Note that TI-BASIC is tokenized, and each token, like `Ans` and `prod(`, is one or two bytes in the calculator's memory.

Input through `Ans` i.e. in the form `{a,b,c}:[program name]`.

Explained:

```
                   sum(Ans)-2*Ans   (a+b+c)-2{a,b,c}={b+c-a,c+a-b,a+b-c}
          Ans*prod(                 {a,b,c}*(b+c-a)(c+a-b)(a+b-c)
      sum(                          (a+b+c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)(a+b-c)
4⁻¹*√(                              √((a+b+c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)(a+b-c)/16)
                                    =√(s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c))
```

Comment: I've converted this to a community wiki as it isn't your own work. We don't really have a solid consensus on this, but feel free to weigh in [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2155/8478) if you disagree with my decision.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
½*Nx
NmnU ×*U q
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=vSpOeApObW5VINcqVSBx&input=MiwzLDQ=)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [ETH](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions) pointing out a redundant newline and some alternative ways to reduce the array.

Comment: I think you can use any of these for the second line, too: `NmnU ×*U q`, `NmnU r*U q`, `Np0 mnU ×q`

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 42 bytes

Based on Heron's formula, high school algebra to golf.

```
=SQRT(((A1+B1)^2-C1^2)*(C1^2-(A1-B1)^2))/4
```

Ungolfed / Unalgebra'ed

```
=SQRT((A1+B1+C1)/2*(((A1+B1+C1)/2)-A1)*(((A1+B1+C1)/2)-B1)*(((A1+B1+C1)/2)-C1))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Julia 0.6.0, 48 bytes

Basically heron's formula:

```
f(a,b,c)=(p=(a+b+c)/2;sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 34 bytes

```
9ksssddlsld++2/d3R-rdls-rdld-***vp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b6RgrGCi8N8yu7i4OCUlpzgnRVvbSD/FOEi3CMgDESm6WlpaZQX//wMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 36 bytes

```lua
sqrt(a*(a-b)*(a-c)*(a-d))((b+c+d)/2)
```

Heron's formula.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/7@4sKhEI1FLI1E3SRNEJoPJFE1NDY0k7WTtFE19I83///8bmfw3NvhvaAEA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=sum -ap`, 40 bytes

```perl
$r=$t=.5*sum@F;map$r*=$t-$_,@F;$_=sqrt$r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lyFalxFbPVKu4NNfBzTo3sUClSAsopKsSrwPkq8TbFhcWlagU/f9vrGCiYPovv6AkMz@v@L@ur6megaEBkPbJLC6xsgotycyxBZrxXzexAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╝0∞♀»♦▓y╩╪
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=bc30ec0caf04b279cad8&i=[2.0,+3.0,+4.0]%0A[3.0,+4.0,+5.0]&a=1&m=2)

Operates triples of floating point numbers.  Uses [Heron's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 16 chars, 32 bytes

```
{√×/(+/⍵÷2)-0,⍵}
```

One has to cenvert the Erone formula if a, b, c are sides of triangle

```
p   =(a+b+c)/2 
Area=√p*(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)
```

to APL language... test

```
  f←{√×/(+/⍵÷2)-0,⍵}
  f 2 3 4
2.90473751
  f 3 4 5
6
```